# Pandoc metadata not appearing in default HTML template

Tags: html, yaml, pandoc

I'm converting org and markdown files to HTML using pandoc. I want to set metadata such as the `title`, `subtitle`, and `author` tags in an external YAML file and have them display using a template. However I can't get anything to appear beyond the normal body conversion.

I'm using the default HTML template. I've run the conversion concatenating the YAML config beforehand:

```
pandoc -t html -o output.html metadata.yaml input.md
```

I also tried including the `yaml_metadata_block` extension:

```
pandoc -t html+yaml_metadata_block -o output.html metadata.yaml input.md
```

Also, I've tried setting the variables in the command itself:

```
pandoc -t html -o output.html -V title="my title" input.md
```

My YAML file looks like this:

```
---
title: "my title"
subtitle: "my subtitle"
author: "the author"
...
```

Inspecting the default html template with `pandoc -D html`, it looks like when `title` etc. are defined, it'll place in a header block:

```
$if(title)$
<header>
<h1 class="title">$title$</h1>
$if(subtitle)$
<p class="subtitle">$subtitle$</p>
$endif$
$for(author)$
<p class="author">$author$</p>
$endfor$
$if(date)$
<p class="date">$date$</p>
$endif$
</header>
```

But in every case, the html file only contains the converted text from `input.md`. I think this is the `$body$` line defined in the default template.

How can I get these fields to appear in my html document?

Answer (score 6):

My goodness, all I was missing is the `-s` attribute!

from the man page:

```
-s, --standalone
          Produce output with an appropriate header and footer (e.g.  a standalone HTML, LaTeX, TEI, or RTF file, not a fragment).  This option is set automat‐
          ically for pdf, epub, epub3, fb2, docx, and odt output.
```

Thus the following command works as expected

```
pandoc -s -t html -o output.html metadata.yaml input.md
```